# Chemical incompatibility between aluminum hydroxide [Al(OH)3] and carbomer polymer [-CH2-CH] N-COOH]

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers, chemical-biology, identification

I am currently adsorbing proteins to an aluminum hydroxide gel.  By adding a carbomer (polymer of acrylic acid cross-linked with allyl sucrose), I achieve a somewhat synergistic formulation.  Shortly after adding the carbomer, a granular precipitate forms that adheres to glass.  Questions: 1) What is this precipitate?; 2) Will my adsorbed protein release from the aluminum hydroxide after carbomer addition?; 3) Is there possible long-term instability of this mixture?  Thank you!